# Golang time parsing does not work properly while working on playground

Tags: datetime, go

I need to parse a datetime string that is generated by a pseudo random datetime generator that uses Unix() function. The generated datetime takes various date and time pairs between 2010 and 2017.
Here's the problem, this version of the code works on both my computer and playground,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := time.Date(2016, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix()
    kk := time.Unix(a, 0)
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST", kk.String())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

But the version below works on playground and panics on my computer,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := time.Date(2018, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix()
    kk := time.Unix(a, 0)
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST", kk.String())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Here's the error,

```
panic: parsing time "2017-12-31 03:00:00 +0300 +03" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST": cannot parse "+03" as "MST"
```

The Go version I use is `go1.8.3 darwin/amd64`.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first thought is the version of golang you are using. I ran the second version in Gogland-EAP, using go 1.8.3 on a Mac, and had no issues. Here's the output: 2017-12-30 19:00:00 -0500 EST

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I should have mentioned the version I use, it's go1.8.3 darwin/amd64. No IDE or anything, I just run it through terminal. Before this version I was using 1.7.2 and updated an hour ago just to see if update would resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Identical to mine. I just did it command line. No problem. Output: go run main.go
2017-12-30 19:00:00 -0500 EST

Comment: I see, it apparently has something to do with my computer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. May want to look at time zone issues as well.

Comment: It's on my mind also. Thanks for the advice! I also realized that not working version's Unix function outputs `2017-12-31 03:00:00 +0300 +03` while the other one outputs `2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0200 EET`. Timezone extensions seems to be different as hell. Also the error message suggests that the problem is related with `+03` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is related with the abbreviation change for `Europe/Istanbul`.

> Turkey switched from EET/EEST (+02/+03) to permanent +03,
>   effective 2016-09-07. (Thanks to Burak AYDIN.) Use "+03" rather
>   than an invented abbreviation for the new time.

Time package currently does not accept +03 as EET/EEST and this problem occurs when using a datetime string that contains `+03` as timezone to parse in form of `2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST`.